# How to find SharePoint Version & SPFx can be used?

Tags: spfx, version

In order to use SPFx, it mentions that "SharePoint 2016 Feature Pack 2" is required.

I have SharePoint 2016 On Premise. But how to find out what version and feature pack is currently installed.

I dont have access to the Server, is there a way to find this information from Client Side or as Site Collection Admin/Full Control access?

Also, how to know the SPFx and its required components are already installed and available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint 2016 with feature pack 2 supports  v1.1.0 of the SharePoint Framework.

Ref: [SharePoint Framework development with SharePoint 2016 Feature Pack 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-2016-support)

I don't know of a way to determine which feature pack is installed without access to the server, ask your farm administrators.

**Update**

Per Dylan Cristy's comment, you could check for the existence of `_layouts/workbench.aspx`. Should look something like this:

[image: Workbench on SharePoint 2016]

**Update**

Updated the image to SharePoint 2016 with Feature Pack 2, not dramatically different.

Comment: Would the `workbench.aspx` page be present even if the server wasn't up to feature pack 2?

Comment: That makes sense. I was just rooting around for the release notes to see if I could come up with a better answer, but looking for `workbench.aspx` is a pretty easy solution.